# How to mount from an IP address using NFS?

Tags: server, 16.04, file-sharing, nfs

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit home server and I followed this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html) to set up the NFS server. My problem is that I'm trying to connect (on my desktop) to it via IP address as the code below:

```
sudo mount 192.168.1.126/exports /local/ubuntu
```

But when I do, I get this:

```
mount: special device 192.168.1.126/exports does not exist
```

Is there a way to connect via IP address only or do you must have a domain and an address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a colon (`:`) after the remote server IP:

```
sudo mount 192.168.1.126:/exports /local/ubuntu
```

Assuming the remote server (`192.168.1.126`) has exported `/exports` and you are mounting it on `/local/ubuntu`.

Although, the preferred solution is to add the mount in `/etc/fstab` so that you do not have to mount it manually everytime. Also `nfs` provides a whole bunch of options while mounting, these provide more finer control over the mount, look at `man 5 nfs`.

Comment: It works, but mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.126:exports.  It means that I have permission issues on the server.

Comment: @SvetlanaBelkin Yes, also apart from NFSv.4 all prior NFS  uses UID/GID, not username/groupname for permission..make sure you have mapped UID/GID or check relevant options..

Comment: @SvetlanaBelkin Your client seems not to be allowed to mount the share. Try `showmount -e 192.168.1.126` to see what really is exported for whom.

Comment: @ridgy svetlana@svetlana-laptop:~$ showmount -e 192.168.1.126
Export list for 192.168.1.126:
/export/Elements 192.168.1.126/24
/export          192.168.1.126/24 Like I said to heemayl, I have new problem and I'm seeking the answer.

Comment: The result of `showmount -e` tells that the server allows access to the share(s) for all comuters in the subnet 192.168.1.0/24. Are you sure your computer's IP address does match that constraint? The message `access denied by server while mounting` implies it does not; UID/GID is not relevant at that moment.